# Securing running mongo servers

Tags: mongodb, security, database-replication, database, nosql

I have replication setup for the mongo without security and authorization. But now I wish to add security by the means of authorization. The setup is like this
`4 boxes : A,B,C,D,` A being the master and rest the slaves. They all are running in no authentication mode. 
Now I wish to add -keyFile option to all and thus ensure login mode for it.

The issue is that I do not want any Down time. I wish to add the security seamlessly without any impact to the end-user site. What step should I follow?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to go around recommended firewall set up and use keys?

Comment: I just want only few people to be able to have production data access. For that I have to add authentication such that I have both read and write users.

Comment: This is a question for system administrators, not for programmers. You should ask on our sister site http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to restart every instance at some point to enable security and authentication.   You cannot run mixed (authentication and no-authentication), so making the switch is not possible without downtime.

All you can do is minimize that downtime by adding the admin user first and making sure your keyfiles are consistent and in place for the restarts as described here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication